# Convert Rdlc to protected PDF

Tags: vb.net

I'm doing a project where I need to convert a pdf report rdlc, and I did that part, but I want to transform this protected, meaning that it can only be read, it can not modify or open with acrobat ... thanks in advance for your answers .... Here I leave the function I'm using and I hope you can tell me that I'm missing or if I should do otherwise:

```
Public Function CreatePDF() As Boolean

    Dim reportType As String = "PDF"
    Dim mimeType As String = Nothing
    Dim encoding As String = Nothing
    Dim deviceInfo As String = "<DeviceInfo><OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat>" & _
                               "<PageWidth>.0in</PageWidth><PageHeight>1in</PageHeight><MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop><MarginLeft>1in</MarginLeft><MarginRight>1in</MarginRight><MarginBottom>0.5in</MarginBottom></DeviceInfo>"
    Dim warnings As Warning() = Nothing
    Dim renderedBytes As Byte()
    Try
        Reporteview.RefreshReport()
        If File.Exists("C:\account_status.pdf") Then
            File.Delete("C:\account_status.pdf")
        End If
        renderedBytes = Reporteview.LocalReport.Render("PDF", Nothing, mimeType, Nothing, ".PDF", Nothing, warnings)
        Dim fs As FileStream = System.IO.File.Create("c:\account_status.pdf", 1, FileOptions.WriteThrough)
        fs.Write(renderedBytes, 0, renderedBytes.Length)
        fs.Close()
        Return True
    Catch ex As AccessViolationException
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: This is off-topic for SO as it's not in English.

Comment: Use `Google Translate` to convert your language.

Comment: @OneFineDay: Who? Me? ;)

Comment: @OneFineDay: Ha ha, gotcha! Nice edit, I just hope the OP understands any answers given.

Comment: @TheBlueDog, well they can use that tool both ways =)